# How to resolve missing dependencies odoo js in odoo 12?

Tags: javascript, jquery, odoo, odoo-12

I am facing missing dependencies odoo js error.  I updated web module, website module but the same error still exist. If any one have any idea please share with me how to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Do you have custom modules installed? Are they in the addons paths?

Comment: @CZoellner yes i have custom module and that one also in addons path